# Тире после пояснительного члена

Tags: пунктуация, тире, пояснительная

*Ниже я подготовил для тебя чек-лист, который поможет тебе соблюдать информационную гигиену — правильно выбрать курс, тренинг или книгу (—) и не стать очередной жертвой «маркетинга знаний».*

Здесь пояснительный оборот. Нужно ли второе тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ниже я подготовил для тебя чек-лист, который поможет тебе соблюдать информационную гигиену: правильно выбрать курс, тренинг или книгу — и не стать очередной жертвой «маркетинга знаний».**

> Встречается постановка двоеточия при пояснительном члене предложения. Обычно двоеточие ставится для того, чтобы избежать двух тире. *Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений – водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами.* ([Пояснительные члены предложения](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html))

Comment: Какое основание для тире? Причинно-следственная связь здесь не подчёркивается, тире, если и ставится, то для того, чтобы закрыть пояснительный оборот. В вашем случае чисто теоретически тире можно поставить для того, чтобы продолжить первое предложение после неполного предложения, связанного с ним бессоюзной связью. Однако я такого синтаксиса не встречал.

Comment: Авторское тире может ставиться для обозначения логического ударения, в данном случае для подчеркивания того факта, что вторая часть являетя результатом. Признаюсь, я подумал, что Вы поставили это тире именно из таких соображений, и постарался сохранить его. Наряду с этим, вариант, предложенный @Jasmin, мне нравится.

Comment: Знаете, а мне нравится ваш вариант. Следовало бы здесь отметить, что "не стать жертвой маркетинга знаний" — это результат. Только вот часть предложения после тире относится к пояснительному обороту или к главной части?

Comment: По-моему, все, что стоит после двоеточия, — пояснительная конструкция.

Answer (score 1):

Ниже я подготовил для тебя чек-лист, который поможет тебе соблюдать информационную гигиену — **правильно выбрать курс, тренинг или книгу  и при этом не стать очередной жертвой «маркетинга знаний».**

Пояснение

1) Нежелательно использовать два разных по функции тире.

2) Второй оборот лучше считать однородным по  отношению к первому, но его значение можно  дифференцировать с помощью наречия "при этом".

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Термин "информационная гигиена" неясен", я его понимаю как информационную разборчивость (чтобы ненужные "знания" не прилипали к человеку). Тогда мой вариант оформления подходит.

2) Если же вы хотите проверить правильность постановки знаков **для своего варианта**, то надо ставить **два тире**, так как на месте разрыва текста нет знаков (стоит одиночный союз И).

**Образцом для такого решения является правило Розенталя,** отнесенное к обособленным пояснительным приложениям, но я думаю, что его можно распространить и на другие пояснительные члены, обособленные с помощью тире: Достали глубиномер — **гирьку на длинной бечёвке** — и промерили глубину.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Comment: Второе тире обозначает не следствие, результат, а закрытие пояснительного члена. Оба тире выполняют одинаковую функцию, только вот я не уверен ставится ли второе тире. Обычно пояснительные конструкции, выделяемые тире, стоят в конце предложения. Нашёл только один пример, где конструкция стоит в середине: "То ли он решил, что ошибся — честного человека не распознал, то ли по другой причине, но он охотно выполнил просьбу"

Comment: Вообще, тут "не стать очередной жертвой маркетинга знаний" скорее относится к "соблюдать информационную гигиену", которое, в свою очередь, появляется оборотом.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, дополнение к ответу.

Comment: появляется — поясняется* (опечатка в комментарии)

Comment: Вы верно поняли метафору. Ну да, наверное, вы правы, что "второй оборот лучше считать однородным по отношению к первому". На каком основании предлагаете вставить наречие "при этом"?

Comment: Я уже писала в ответе про наречие "при этом".  Ели отношения не полностью однородные, то их  можно дифференцировать  (уточнить) с помощью различных наречий. В данном случае "при этом" указывает на то, что второе действие сопровождает первое.

Comment: Кстати, вы не считаете, что в нашем случае "приложение" выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение, и второе тире опускается согласно тому же Розенталю?

Comment: Розенталь говорит о другой конструкции, а именно об обособленном приложении. В данной теме это может выглядеть примерно так: Этот чек-лист об  информационной гигиене  - правильном выборе источника информации //поможет тебе не стать очередной жертвой «маркетинга знаний».

Comment: А можно распространить это на другие пояснительные члены и оставить конструкцию как есть?

Comment: Думаю, что распространить нельзя: у Вас не приложение, а несогласованное определение, выраженное однородным рядом.  Да и зачем распространять,  правила позволяют обособлять с помощью тире пояснительную конструкцию в конце предложения. Одного тире вполне достаточно.

Comment: Напомню, что мы сейчас обсуждаем случай, когда последний инфинитив не входит в пояснительную конструкцию, поэтому она стоит не в конце, а посередине предложения.